# Waiting for process to end before activating app

Tags: shell, vbscript

A bit of back ground:

I'm trying to create a script that will sign a specific user into a program depending on the time of day.  Every time the wrong person is signed in on the incorrect hours, it has the potential to cost the company $20,000 in license violation costs.

I tried a few things, the simplest being a spreadsheet that used simple if statements to determine log in credentials and open the program in the shell.  After a predetermined wait time, it would enter the credentials.  This was problematic due to the varying speeds of the systems.

I thought I would have a go at VBScript.  How much different could it be than VBA I thought...  Well it's obvious after a couple of days that I'm lost.

Here is my script:

```vb
Sub QADHelper()

'Logs the correct user into QAD depending on the time of day

HourNow = Time
Dim Shell, WMI, PID
Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:!\\root\cimv2")

'Note: Literal quotes are used because of the space between "program" and "files"

WSHShell.Run """C:\Program Files\QAD\QAD Enterprise Applications 2007.1\QAD.Applications.exe"""

PID = WaitforProcess("QAD.Applications.exe", 5)

If PID >0 Then
    Shell.AppActivate PID
Else
    WScript.Echo "Could not reach QAD"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If


'This is where the QAD log in credentials are stored

If HourNow >= "06:15:00" Then  
WSHShell.SendKeys "username1"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WSHShell.SendKeys "password1"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

ElseIf HourNow >= "14:15:01" Then  
WSHShell.SendKeys "username2"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WSHShell.SendKeys "password2"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

ElseIf HourNow >= "22:15:01" Then  
WSHShell.SendKeys "username3"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
WSHShell.SendKeys "password3"
WSHShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"

Else
    WScript.Echo "This isn't working properly"
    WScript.Quit 1
End If

End Sub

Function WaitForProcess(imageName, tries)

    Dim wql, process

    wql = "SELECT ProcessId FROM Win32_Process WHERE Name = '" & imageName & "'"

    WaitForProcess = 0

    While tries > 0 And WaitForProcess = 0

        For Each process In WMI.ExecQuery(wql)
            WaitForProcess = process.ProcessId
        Next
        If WaitForProcess = 0 Then
            WScript.Sleep 1000
            tries = tries - 1
        End If
    Wend

End Function
```

Admittedly, I don't know what much of this is as I aped it off of other scripts.  For example, I'm not sure what WMI is and what its role is in this script.  The error message this script returns is a compilation error.  It calls out line 60 character 1, the start of my function.

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: I forgot to mention, this is a startup script.  The reason there is no line to shut the shell program down at any point is because I have a batch file that closes all programs at a certain time and restarts the computer.  The startup procedure re-initiates this script.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your `WaitForProcess()` function is nested within your `QADHelper` sub. VBScript does not allow nested subroutines.
2. Just because your `WaitForProcess()` function finds the EXE running doesn't mean its window is shown and it's ready to accept input. You may want to use `AppActivate` in a timeout loop to ensure your `SendKeys` commands reach their target window.
3. You're creating a shell object named `WSHShell`, which you're using for `Run`, but you also need to use it for your `AppActivate` call and all of your `SendKeys` statements. You're using `Shell`, which is undeclared by your script.
4. `SendKeys` expects a string parameter. Keys like `ENTER` and `TAB` need to be enclosed in braces within the string:

   ```
   WSHShell.SendKeys "{TAB}"
   WSHShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
   ```
5. You need to use `ElseIf` instead of `Else If`. `ElseIf` is treated as a clause to your original `If`. `Else If` creates a nested `If` that will expect an `End If`.

Comment: I apologize for my lack of knowledge, but if the function isn't nested in the sub than how do I reference it?  Do I need to create a separate script and call it in my sub?  un-nesting it within the same file creates an error at "End Sub"

Comment: See the new #5, above. I think your `Else If` statements may be causing some control-flow issues. Try correcting that and see if it fixes your `Sub` error when unnesting.

Comment: Well, it doesn't return an error anymore.  But it isn't doing much of anything.  I'm going to update the code in my op.

Comment: Thanks again for anything you can think of.

Comment: You've still got some `Shell` references. Fix those and then determine where your script if going off the rails.

Comment: Alright, I've removed all references to "Shell".  The only instance of the word "shell" in the script is Set WSHShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

It seems to be doing something when I run the script, but it's not opening the program or returning an error.

Comment: And what issue are you facing now?

Comment: The script should be opening the program "QAD" and entering log in credentials according to the time of day.  Instead it does nothing.  It seems to initiate, but it returns no errors and opens no program.

Comment: Are you calling your `Sub`?

Comment: OMG wow.  Sorry about that.  It runs now but I'm getting a compilation error at the "Set WMI" line saying that the remote server machine is not available or does not exist.

Comment: With so many issues, your question is probably better off on a site like [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/). StackOverflow is meant for specific questions about specific issues. But let me throw one more bone your way. Use `Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\CIMV2")` to create a WMI object to query the local machine. Also, you're declaring your `WMI` variable in `QADHelper` but using it in `WaitForProcess`. That's not going to work.

Comment: @Bond CR is for working code only, please oh please read [A Guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: Thank you @Bond for all of your assistance.  I'll keep plugging away at it until it works.